# Maybe someone have the same in ie11 React #109 error only in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

This problem heppends only in ie11 in production build

Invariant Violation: Minified React error #109; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=109&args[]=t for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

cmmon.webpack.js

```
const getEntry = () => {
    let res = [
        helpers.root(srcName, "index.js")
    ];

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
        res = [
            "react-hot-loader/patch",
            "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5000",
            "webpack/hot/only-dev-server"
        ].concat(res);
    }

    return res;
};

const getStylLoader = () => {
    let res = {
        test : /\.styl$/,
        exclude : /node_modules/,
        loader : "style-loader!css-loader?modules=false&sourceMap=true!stylus-loader?sourceMap"
    };

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        res = Object.assign({}, res, {
            loader : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback : "style-loader",
                use : "css-loader?modules=false&minimize=true&sourceMap=true!stylus-loader?sourceMap"
            })
        });
    }

    return res;
};

module.exports = {
    entry : {
        "vendor" : ["react", "react-dom", "react-router", "redux", "react-router-redux", "jquery"],
        "app" : ["babel-polyfill"].concat(getEntry())
    },

    context : helpers.root(srcName),

    resolve : {

        modules : [
            "web_modules",
            "node_modules",
            "spritesmith-generated",
            helpers.root(srcName)
        ],

        extensions : [".js", ".styl", ".css"]

    },

    externals : {
        "cheerio" : "window",
        "react/addons" : true,
        "react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment" : true,
        "react/lib/ReactContext" : true
    },

    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                enforce : "pre",
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loader : "eslint-loader",
                options : {
                    fix : process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
                },
                include : [helpers.root(srcName), /node_modules\/react-redux-toastr/],
                exclude : helpers.root(srcName, "core", "routes.js")
            },
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loader : "babel-loader",
                include : [helpers.root(srcName), /react-redux-toastr/],
                exclude : /node_modules\/(?!"react-redux-toastr")/,
                query : {
                    presets : ["react"]
                }
            },
            {
                test : /\.css$/,
                use : [
                    { loader : "style-loader"},
                    {
                        loader : "css-loader",
                        query : {
                            modules : false,
                            minimize : false
                        }
                    },
                    { loader : "resolve-url-loader" }
                ],
            },
            getStylLoader(),
            {
                test : /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                use : [
                    { loader : "file-loader?name=i/[hash].[ext]"},
                    {
                        loader : "image-webpack-loader",
                        query : {
                            progressive : true,
                            pngquant : {
                                quality : "65-90",
                                speed : 4
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test : /\.svg$/,
                use : [
                    { loader : "babel-loader"},
                    {
                        loader : "react-svg-loader",
                        query : {
                            es5 : true,
                            svgo : {
                                plugins : [{cleanupIDs : false}],
                                floatPrecision : 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                test : /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader : "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            {
                test : /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader : "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            {
                test : /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader : "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
            },
            {
                test : /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader : "file-loader"
            }

        ],
    },
    plugins : [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery : "jquery",
            $ : "jquery",
            jquery : "jquery",
            Tether : "tether",
            "window.Tether" : "tether",
            Alert : "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
            Button : "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
            Carousel : "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
            Collapse : "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
            Dropdown : "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
            Popover : "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
            Scrollspy : "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
            Tab : "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
            Tooltip : "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
            Util : "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
            Modal : "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",

            "Promise" : "es6-promise",
            "fetch" : "imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch",

            /* it uses to demo a multitenacy. In case of second client we expect to see different color_scheme
             * and  backend will provide a different data */
            SECOND_CLIENT : process.env.SECOND_CLIENT ? process.env.SECOND_CLIENT : false
        }),

        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options : {
                context : helpers.root(srcName),
                output : {path : "./"},

                stylus : {
                    use : [poststylus(["autoprefixer"])]
                },

                eslint : {
                    configFile : ".eslintrc",
                    failOnWarning : false,
                    failOnError : false
                }
            }
        }),


        new SpritesmithPlugin({
            src : {
                cwd : helpers.root(srcName, "assets/images/icons"),
                glob : "*.png"
            },
            target : {
                image : helpers.root(srcName, "assets/images/spritesmith_generated/sprite.png"),
                css : helpers.root(srcName, "assets/images/spritesmith_generated/sprite.styl")
            },
            apiOptions : {
                cssImageRef : "../images/spritesmith_generated/sprite.png"
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

production.webpack.js

```
    module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
        devtool : "source-map",

        output : {
            path : helpers.root("dist"),
            publicPath : "/",
            filename : "[name].[hash].bundle.js",
            chunkFilename : "[id].[hash].bundle.chunk.js"
        },

        plugins : [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                rootPath : "",
                template : "index.ejs"
            }),
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name : "vendor",
                minChunks : Infinity,
                filename : "vendor.bundle.js"
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "process.env" : {
                    NODE_ENV : JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                sourceMap : true,
                compress : {
                    warnings : false,
                    screw_ie8 : true,
                    conditionals : true,
                    unused : true,
                    comparisons : true,
                    sequences : true,
                    dead_code : true,
                    evaluate : true,
                    if_return : true,
                    join_vars : true,
                },
                output : {
                    comments : false
                },
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].[hash].css"),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    from : helpers.root("src", "assets/static"),
                    to : "static"
                },
                {
                    from : helpers.root("robots.txt"),
                    to : ""
                }
            ])
        ]
    });
```